# Suppress signal occurrence

Tags: bash

I have a bash script similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout -s ALRM 1 sleep 5
```

This script should trigger the timeout and return with an exit code of 124.
It does, however it also prints the following text to stderr:

```
a.sh: line 2:   604 Alarm clock             timeout -s ALRM 1 sleep 5
```

The bash version is

> bash --version
> GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (arm-mut-linux-gnueabi)

What is causing this debug output? How do I supress it?

Here's a list of my shopt

```
# shopt
autocd          off
assoc_expand_once       off
cdable_vars     off
cdspell         off
checkhash       off
checkjobs       off
checkwinsize    on
cmdhist         on
compat31        off
compat32        off
compat40        off
compat41        off
compat42        off
compat43        off
compat44        off
complete_fullquote      on
direxpand       off
dirspell        off
dotglob         off
execfail        off
expand_aliases  on
extdebug        off
extglob         off
extquote        on
failglob        off
force_fignore   on
globasciiranges on
globstar        off
gnu_errfmt      off
histappend      off
histreedit      off
histverify      off
hostcomplete    on
huponexit       off
inherit_errexit off
interactive_comments    on
lastpipe        off
lithist         off
localvar_inherit        off
localvar_unset  off
login_shell     off
mailwarn        off
no_empty_cmd_completion off
nocaseglob      off
nocasematch     off
nullglob        off
progcomp        on
progcomp_alias  off
promptvars      on
restricted_shell        off
shift_verbose   off
sourcepath      on
xpg_echo        off
```

Comment: Please don't recommend `timeout 2> /dev/null` (:

Comment: It prints nothing in my terminal. What system are you on? What is the environment? For your shell to print something, I think the `ALRM` signal would have been raised to your shell, not to `sleep`, which is strange. What is the output of `sleep --version`?

Comment: On my desktop it also doesn't print anything. Is has to be something with either the compile options of the bash or some magic setting (that's why I posted the output of `shopt`).
It's not sleeps fault (I use a busybox btw. maybe I should look into that as wel..). It also happens like this `kill -s USR1 $$`.

Comment: `arm-mut-linux-gnueabi` Or the kernel. Please post details of your environment - kernel version, architecture, used tools versions, distribution. `I use a busybox btw` Post busybox version. Make sure you are really running `bash` and post it's version, not running other shell.

Comment: I'm not really certain if the kernel has anything to do with it. It's a yocto based system, busybox v1.32.0. I'm really running a bash, as you see in the very first line of my script it says `/bin/bash` and `/bin/bash` is really a bash.

Comment: `first line of my script it says /bin/bash` And you may run your script with `sh ./thescrript` effectively ignoring the first line and running it under other shell... I can't get the output to be in format `filename: line number: <some number> <strsignal()> <command>`, nor I can't find it in bash sources. What do you think that `604` might be? Can you write a C program and check what is the value of `SIGALRM` (should be 14)?

Comment: I think the only way forward would be to run your program under `strace -ff bash ./yoruscript` and inspect the output - does bash really print the output? Does it receive the signal? `strace` will provide answers.

Comment: 604 is the PID of the child process it seems.  The write comes from the bash itself: `write(2, "./a.sh: line 2:  1451 Alarm cloc"..., 72./a.sh: line 2:  1451 Alarm clock             timeout -s ALRM 1 sleep 5
) = 72` Not from a child (there is no `[pid ...]` in front, when running strace with `-ff`.

Comment: I really do appreciate your help, but I'm not really sure where to start searching. I was afraid, that you can't reproduce it. I try to dig a little bit deeper here. Thank you very much so far!

Comment: It is the same line that gets printed when I use, e.g. `disown 2938`. When I do that on my desktop, it prints a similar line: `./a.sh: line 2: disown: 12938: no such job`, so bash really has such printout. Now I need to find why it does it for signals on my device (:

Comment: `kill -s USR1 $$` is a different case where it is the parent shell that prints *User signal 1*, not the shell that executes the script. On Bash 5.1 I can't reproduce the issue that you described in your question.

Comment: This is where the line get's printed: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c?h=bash-5.0#n4119

Comment: So, I did some digging:
on my device `termsig` (see line [4067](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c?h=bash-5.0#n4067)) is `14` whereas on my desktop it's `0`. That's why the `if` is true and prints out the error message... I have no clue, what that means, but it is something.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have verified it by inserting a custom `fprintf` so that is definitely the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like on your system, Busybox's `timeout` comes first in `$PATH`.

On my Debian Linux:

```
[STEP 101] $ cat foo.sh
busybox timeout -s ALRM 1 sleep 5
echo rc=$?
/usr/bin/timeout -s ALRM 1 sleep 5
echo rc=$?
[STEP 102] $ bash foo.sh
foo.sh: line 1: 86649 Alarm clock             busybox timeout -s ALRM 1 sleep 5
rc=142
rc=124
[STEP 103] $
```

To suppress the `Alarm clock` message you can

```
{ timeout ...; } 2> /dev/null
```

---

Regarding the `Alarm clock` message I tried some common signals:

```
[STEP 104] $ cat bar.sh
for sig in INT QUIT TERM PIPE KILL SEGV HUP ALRM USR1; do
    sleep 1 &
    echo - $sig
    kill -$sig %%
    wait
done
[STEP 105] $ bash bar.sh
- INT
- QUIT
- TERM
- PIPE
- KILL
bar.sh: line 5: 86934 Killed                  sleep 1
- SEGV
bar.sh: line 5: 86935 Segmentation fault      sleep 1
- HUP
bar.sh: line 5: 86936 Hangup                  sleep 1
- ALRM
bar.sh: line 5: 86937 Alarm clock             sleep 1
- USR1
bar.sh: line 5: 86938 User defined signal 1   sleep 1
[STEP 106] $
```

Comment: But [busybox timeout](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/coreutils/timeout.c) doesn't write the message. I suspect it's `busybox` - `ash` shell that does write it.

Comment: That's it! On my device `timeout` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/busybox.nosuid`. I don't have coreutils timeout installed. So what the heck is going on? Is `busybox.timeout` violating something that coreutils `timeout` does right?

Comment: that seems to be the case that busybox's timeout is not following coreutils behavior. or coreutils is not following busybox? :)

Comment: no, but `setsid busybox timeout -s ALRM 1 sleep 5` does silence it, but it also sets `rc=0` which is unfortunate.

Comment: @hellow as a workaround you can `{ timeout ...; } 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Nice catch. BusyBox timeout forks and calls execve(sleep) in the parent, then its children sends SIGALRM on timeout. And GNU timeout does the exact opposite :D This is amusing